# How do I use a Haskell library function?

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell newbie, trying to accomplish a Caesar cipher exercise.

In a `.hs` file, I defined the following function:

```
let2int :: Char -> Int
let2int c = ord c - ord 'a'
```

Then I attempt to load this into GHCi by typing `:l caeser.hs` and I get the following error message:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( caeser.hs, interpreted )
caeser.hs:2:12: Not in scope: `ord'
caeser.hs:2:20: Not in scope: `ord'
```

From the book I was using, I had the impression that `ord` and `chr` were standard functions for converting between characters and integers, but it seems evident that I need to "import" them or something.  How is this done?

Comment: I was looking to load a library from the GHCi command line, I found you can use this command at the command line:
`:m Data.Char`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are standard functions but you need to import them from the right module first.  Add

```
import Data.Char
```

to ceaser.hs and it should work.

See also http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/index.html for the full set of libraries that ship with the compiler.

Comment: Is it considered bad practice to use `Data.Char.ord` there instead of importing it, esp. if `ord` is used only once? I understand it makes reading the program harder by "hiding" imports into the program body.

Comment: @hyiltiz I suggest you ask that as a separate question, as its a complicated trade-off. Usual practice is to import common libraries unqualified unless they have name clashes (e.g. `import qualified Data.Map as M`).

Answer (score 9):

In "Haskell 2010", `ord` lives in `Data.Char`

So you'll want `import Data.Char` or `import Data.Char (ord)`

In "Haskell 98", `ord` can be found in the module `Char`.

A great tool for finding functions and their modules is

http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Answer (score 4):

If you use hoogle to search for [ord](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=ord) you'll see that function lives in / is exported by the [Data.Char](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-Char.html#v%3aord) module.  So just import this module:

```
import Data.Char
```

Learn to use hoogle.  Many of the SO Haskell questions asked are a result of people not knowing about Hoogle... and sometimes they must not know about Google either (not to discourage you from asking, but do use hoogle).

In the future, for larger libraries that might have conflicting names with existing functions you can either limit your import to just the function you care about:

```
import Data.Char (ord)
```

Or import it `qualified`:

```
import qualified Data.Char as C
...
func x y = C.ord x - C.ord y
```

(a third method, using `hiding`, works but I detest that method)

Comment: I did check Hoogle, but didn't know what to do with the information that I received.  Thanks.